# Regular expression to match alphanumeric, hyphen, underscore and space string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a string that contains alphanumeric, hyphen, underscore and space.

Hyphen, underscore, space and numbers are optional, but the first and last characters must be letters.

For example, these should all match:

```
abc
abc def
abc123
ab_cd
ab-cd
```

I tried this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]+$
```

but it matches with space, underscore or hyphen at the start/end, but it should only allow in between.

Comment: i tried this ^[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]+$ but it takes space,underscore and hyphen at the start and end, it should allow space in between

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34916893/5678086

Comment: Use [`^[a-zA-Z0-9][\w -]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/mF3xX9/1)

Comment: @Tushar: `\s` will allow tab, newline and carriage return too, OP didn't specified those. Besides the first character set should match many characters, not just one.

Comment: @thushar its taking space at the end of string :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a simple character class wrapped with letter chars:

```
^[a-zA-Z]([\w -]*[a-zA-Z])?$
```

This matches input that starts and ends with a letter, including just a single letter.

There is a bug in your regex: You have the hyphen in the middle of your characters, which makes it a character *range*. ie `[9-_]` means "every char between `9` and `_` inclusive.

If you want a literal dash in a character class, put it first or last or escape it.

Also, prefer the use of `\w` "word character", which is all letters and numbers and the underscore in preference to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` - it's easier to type and read.

Comment: I believe OP doesn't want to allow special character at start/end

Comment: the issue with this is that it allows consecutive `--` and `__` at the middle. How can i solve that

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi to prevent consecutive non-letters add a negative look-ahead for them anchored to start, ie add `(?!.*\W\W)` immediately after `^`

Answer (score 2):

I tried using following regex:

```
/^\w+([\s-_]\w+)*$/
```

This allows alphanumeric, underscore, space and dash.
[More details](https://forums.asp.net/t/1063608.aspx?Regex%20check%20for%20alphanumeric%20hyphen%20underscore%20space)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[\w -]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pS7iR7/2)

This will only allow alphanumerics at start and end.

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement of including space, hyphen, underscore and alphanumeric characters you can use `\w` shorthand character set for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Escape the hyphen using `\-` as it usually used for character range inside character set.

To negate the space and hyphen at the beginning and end I have used `[^\s\-]`.

So complete regex becomes `[^\s\-][\w \-]+[^\s\-]`

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/uZ6bW2/3) is the working demo.

Comment: @Muddu Patil: I guess you don't want whitespaces at the starting or end either. That's why I used `\s`.