# How to write a regular expression that matches this pattern but also allows one character to any number of characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression that can contain Latin letters, digits, the underscore (_), the minus (-), and the point (.) symbols but the point symbol cannot be used as the first or the last symbol. I believe I need to use some sort of quantifier because the pattern I have now only works with 3 or more characters. I need it to work even with just one character, it just can't be the (.)point symbol. See my current pattern below:

```
const emailAcctName = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]$/;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to match alphanumeric, hyphen, underscore and space string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916716/regular-expression-to-match-alphanumeric-hyphen-underscore-and-space-string)

Comment: 93 steps: `^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?:\.+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)*$`

https://regex101.com/r/Zuk4yA/1


vs 584 steps: `^(?!^\.)(?!.*\.$)[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$`

https://regex101.com/r/NhJIaA/1
The loopy is the better option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Pattern:

```
const emailAcctName = /^(?!^\.)(?!.*\.$)[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$/;
```

### Explanation:

```
^               Start of string
(?!^\.)         Negative lookahead: Do not match if the string starts with a period
(?!.*\.$)       Negative lookahead: Do not match if the string ends with a period
[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+ Match one or more Latin letters, digits, underscore, hyphen, or period symbols
$               End of string
```

### Tests:

```js
const emailAcctName = /^(?!^\.)(?!.*\.$)[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$/;


console.log(emailAcctName.test("jane_.doe")); // true
console.log(emailAcctName.test("jane.doe_")); // true
console.log(emailAcctName.test("jane-doe.")); // false
console.log(emailAcctName.test("a.b")); // true
console.log(emailAcctName.test(".jane-doe")); // false
```

Comment: This fails the test case `a.b` because you have an extra `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` near the end of your expression.  I believe it also fails `a...b`

Comment: You are correct it would fail the test case "a.b", I've updated and tested it now it's okay!

Comment: You changed the expression but didn't update your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Match the first character, followed by an optional match of any amount of the inner characters and a single last character.

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-](?:[a-zA-Z0-9._-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_-])?$/`

- `^` matches the start of the string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` matches one or more Latin letter, digit, underscore or minus symbol
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]` matches one or more Latin letter, digit, underscore or minus symbol and the dot
- `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9._-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_-])?` matches zero or one repetitions of a non-capturing group that contains any amount of the specified characters (including the dot) followed by a single occurrence of the specified characters (excluding the dot)
- `$` matches the end of the string

```js
const pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-](?:[a-zA-Z0-9._-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_-])?$/;

['f', 'fo', 'foo', 'f.o'].forEach(
  (subject) => {
    console.log(`Match "${subject}": ${pattern.test(subject) ? '✅' : '❌'}`);
  }
);
['.', '.f', 'f.'].forEach(
  (subject) => {
    console.log(`No Match "${subject}": ${!pattern.test(subject) ? '✅' : '❌'}`);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the dot is only allowed in the middle, you can just sandwich the dot's between
`[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` 's.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?:\.+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/Zuk4yA/1

```
 ^                             # BOL
 [a-zA-Z0-9_-]+                # Required class, one or more
 (?: \.+ [a-zA-Z0-9_-]+ )*     # Optional repeating dot followed by repeating class
 $                             # EOL
```

This appears to be significantly faster than assertion methods.